# protecting video hotlink by one time url path. (vk.com in example)

Tags: php, hotlinking

How can I protect my videos from hotlinking?

For example: http://vk.com/video215336036_165406371

when you look at the source code, vk.com provides an one-time usage video path such as

http://cs523402v4.vk.me/u215336036/videos/d436dc950c.240.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a directory inaccessible from the outside world where you have all your video files. Then you could have a database table with a structure like:

```
videos
---------------
id
uri
temp_url
timeout
```

Where `uri` is the location of your real video file and `temp_url` is a random URL that you generate. The `timeout` field contains a timestamp describing when the `temp_url` expires and you have to generate a new one. You could set the timeout to 5 minutes from when you generate a new `temp_url` or 10 minutes. Up to you.